# Google Identity Platform Authentication using OIDC (in Dart/Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, openid-connect, google-identity, google-identity-toolkit

I need some assistance setting up OIDC auth in Google's Identity Platform. I have setup Oauth2 authentication before, but this is slightly different, and I feel like I'm missing something basic, and that's why it's not working. I'm following the [instructions here](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/oidc#web-version-9_1). Using these, I've setup the provider to look similar to this:[image: OIDC Setup]

Then underneath that it specifies as a redirect: `https://my-fancy-project.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler`. The issuer has an appropriate [.well-known/openid-configuration](https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/oauth2/.well-known/openid-configuration)

So, on the Sandbox I'm working in, I've setup a new application for oauth2, received the clientId (seen in the image above as `12345-67890-abcdef-ghijklm`), and specifying the redirect URL for the application to be `https://my-fancy-project.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler`.

In my Flutter application, I call the following method in my dart code:

```dart
Future<void> request(Uri fhirCallback) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  firebaseAuth.FirebaseAuth auth = firebaseAuth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final provider = firebaseAuth.OAuthProvider('oidc.brand-new-auth');
  // provider.setScopes(['openid', 'profile', 'fhirUser']);
  final res1 = await auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
}
```

Which launches a popup window, thinks for a moment, closes, and then gives the following error message:

```
POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp?key=alphanumeric-string 400

[firebase_auth/invalid-credential] Error getting verification code from oidc.brand-new-auth 
response: error=unsupported_response_type&state=another-string_of-alphanumeric-characters-here

js_primitives.dart:30 dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49  throw_
packages/firebase_auth_web/firebase_auth_web.dart 375:7                       signInWithPopup
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 60:31            <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1658:54                                          runBinary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 162:22                                    handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 778:46                                    handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 799:13                                    _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 574:5                                     [_completeError]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 665:7                                     callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15           <fn>
```

But for this kind of authentication I'm not specifically setting the response type, so I'm not sure how to fix this error.

Oh, and if I try instead to go with `Code Flow` instead of `Implicit Flow (id_token)`, generating the secret key for the app and copying it into the Provider, then when I try and authenticate I recieve:

```
[firebase_auth/invalid-credential] The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired.
js_primitives.dart:30 dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49  throw_
packages/firebase_auth_web/firebase_auth_web.dart 375:7                       signInWithPopup
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 60:31            <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1658:54                                          runBinary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 162:22                                    handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 778:46                                    handleError
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 799:13                                    _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 574:5                                     [_completeError]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 665:7                                     callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15           <fn>
```

Does anyone see anything obvious that I'm doing wrong with my setup?